# Problem with `DataFrame.to_latex()` escape argument

Tags: python, pandas, latex

If `escape` argument in [`DataFrame.to_latex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) is `True`, then the values in columns are escaped (`% -> \\%`).

Can I somehow specify for which columns values should be escaped? Sometimes I don't want to escape all of them.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the input, code attempt and expected output, so that we can better understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

Use [pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1", "%"], "b": ["2", "%"], "c": ["3", "%"]})
styler = df.style
latex = styler.format(subset=["b"], escape="latex").to_latex()
print(latex)
```

This produces the following LaTeX table:

```
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  & a &  b & c \\
0 & 1 &  2 & 3 \\
1 & % & \% & % \\
\end{tabular}
```

In this result only the '%' in column *b* is escaped.

More information and examples can be found in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex.html).